# How can I estimate error when computing improper integral with a finite interval?

Tags: integration, approximate-integration, rounding-error, simpsons-rule

I'm trying to evaluate integrals of the form $$I = \int ^{\infty }_{a} f( x) dx$$
Where $a$ is any real number. In order to estimate this integral, I pick some large positive number $M$ and instead evaluate $$I_{\text{approx}} = \int ^{M}_{a} f( x) dx.$$
I am using [Simpson's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) to estimate the integrals. So given the large number $M$ and the step size used for Simpson's Rule, $\Delta x$, how do I estimate $\displaystyle |I\ -\ I_{\text{approx}} |$?

Comment: We have:$$I-I_\mathrm{approx}=\int_M^\infty f(x)~\mathrm dx$$so it depends on the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: You are going to have to find some function $g$ such that $|f(x)| \le g(x)$ for $x > M$ and such that $e(M) = \int_M^\infty g(x)\,dx$ is known. Then you know that $|I - I_{approx}| \le e(M)$.

Comment: Note that (semi-)infinite intervals are usually handled [differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw%E2%80%93Curtis_quadrature#Integration_on_infinite_and_semi-infinite_intervals).